How to keep a program running in turtle that uses tinker buttons? (python)
So I've been trying to keep this program running once opened without idle,
however I have used tinker buttons to be able to create a UI and will not work if a loop or sleep function after them
I am using python 3.12.3 on Windows 11
I tried to find a solution online, however I cant find anything
I have also tried putting the "make button" command in a loop / a loop after the "make button" command but it wont respond
a time.sleep() also doesn't work
(I know the code is a mess)
import time
import turtle
from turtle import Screen
from tkinter import *

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(width=1000, height=400)
screen.title("WBT war stat calculator")
screen.bgcolor("light blue")
canvas = screen.getcanvas()

save_mil = ""
save_diplo = ""
save_eco = ""
save_land = ""

def update_total():
    if not save_mil == "":
        if not save_diplo == "":
            if not save_eco == "":
                if not save_land == "":
                    write_total.clear()
                    stat1 = ((((save_eco / 3) * 2) + (save_diplo / 3) + save_mil) / 2) * save_land
                    write_total.write(stat1, font=("Arial",30))

def make_text(x, y):
    writer = turtle.Turtle()
    writer.penup()
    writer.speed(0)
    writer.hideturtle()
    writer.goto(x, y)
    return writer

def make_textbox(title1, des1, title2, des2, limit, type1):
    answer = screen.textinput(title1, des1)
    global save_mil
    global save_diplo
    global save_eco
    global save_land
    if answer == None:
        pass
    else:
        try:
            stat = float(answer)
            if stat > limit:
                pass
            else:
                if type1 == 1:
                    save_mil = stat
                    write_mil.clear()
                    write_mil.write(stat, font=("Arial",30))
                if type1 == 2:
                    save_diplo = stat
                    write_diplo.clear()
                    write_diplo.write(stat, font=("Arial",30))
                if type1 == 3:
                    save_eco = stat
                    write_eco.clear()
                    write_eco.write(stat, font=("Arial",30))
                if type1 == 4:
                    save_land = stat
                    write_land.clear()
                    write_land.write(stat, font=("Arial",30))
                update_total()
        except:
            stat = (limit + 1)

        while stat > limit:
                if answer == None:
                    stat = 1

                else:
                    try:
                        answer = screen.textinput(title2, des2)
                        stat = float(answer)
                        if stat > limit:
                            pass
                        else:
                            if type1 == 1:
                                save_mil = stat
                                write_mil.clear()
                                write_mil.write(stat, font=("Arial",30))
                            if type1 == 2:
                                save_diplo = stat
                                write_diplo.clear()
                                write_diplo.write(stat, font=("Arial",30))
                            if type1 == 3:
                                save_eco = stat
                                write_eco.clear()
                                write_eco.write(stat, font=("Arial",30))
                            if type1 == 4:
                                save_land = stat
                                write_land.clear()
                                write_land.write(stat, font=("Arial",30))
                            update_total()
                    except:
                        pass


def textbox_mil():
    make_textbox(" ", "What are the military stats? 1 - 10", " ", "What are the military stats again? 1 - 10", 10, 1)

def textbox_diplo():
    make_textbox(" ", "Great, what are the diplomatic stats now? 1 - 10", " ", "Sorry, what are the diplomatic stats now? 1 - 10", 10, 2)
            
def textbox_eco():
    make_textbox(" ", "Eco stats? 1 - 10", " ", "Eco stats again? 1 - 10", 10, 3)
    
def textbox_land():
    make_textbox(" ", "How much of the earth do you have by percentage? (as decimal)", " ", "Repeat how much of the earth do you have by percentage? (as decimal)", 1, 4)


def make_button(x_pos, y_pos, text_t, command_d):
    button = Button(canvas.master, text = text_t, command = command_d)
    button.pack()
    button.place(x = x_pos, y = y_pos)



mil_button = make_button(100, 70, "Military", textbox_mil)
diplo_button = make_button(100, 140, "Diplomatic", textbox_diplo)
eco_button = make_button(100, 210, "Economic", textbox_eco)
land_button = make_button(100, 280, "Land%", textbox_land)

write_mil = make_text(-300, 100)
write_diplo = make_text(-300, 30)
write_eco = make_text(-300, -40)
write_land = make_text(-300, -110)
write_total = make_text(-90, -40)
write_extra = make_text(-100, 200)
write_extra.pendown()
write_extra.goto(-100,-200)
write_extra.penup()
write_extra.goto(-90,100)
write_extra.write("TOTAL:", font=("Arial",30))


Is turtle.mainloop() as the last line in your program what you're looking for?

I suggest you mark this question as answered by accepting the answer (instead mentioning it in the title), else people filtering by not answered questions will erroneously get yours shown.

I suggest you vote to close this question as due to a "typo". this means the question arose from a trivial issue (forgetting the mainloop invocation...). the first comment by ggorlen is sufficient to help OP.
